# how to find the matching string between '{ } ' in node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

My sample string is

```
var str = "My name is {name}.from {area}";
```

I need both {name} and {area} separately from that string.

**I TRIED**

```
var s = "My name is {name}.from {area}";
var matches = s.match(/\{(.*?)\}/);
console.log(matches);
```

It gives only the first occurence.
How to get both the strings **{name} {area}**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the global flag to the regular expression:

```
var matches = s.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g);
```

This will get you all of the matches of the regular expression, not just the first one.

Comment: @shan: If you find answer is helpful, then you should accept it.

Comment: yeah i will accept. It says after 8 minutes only u can accept.So why...:)